# How remove first symbol (ampersand (&)) from GET request URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html

I faced with an issue, while I sending Ajax request with data :

```
myData={Id: "1", userId : "531"};
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: 'url_example?',
  data: myData,
    success: function (data) {
    },
    error: function () {
    }
```

I receiving next request :
https://10.10.10.11/url_example?&Id=1&userId=531

How I can avoid first symbol(&)(after url_example?)   from current request ?
Thanks.

Comment: Remove the `?` from `"url_example?"`

Answer (score 1):

On the receiving end it doesn't matter if you have an extra & in the query string.

This: url?&a=1&b=2
is the same as
This: url?a=1&b=2

Depending on the server-side language you use, you can trim off the "&" on the Request_URI string. But again it's superficial treatment.

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the "?" from the URL parameter. It is implicit from the type: "GET" parameter.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "url_example",
```

and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Once you remove the question mark in the url
    url: 'url_example?' to url: 'url_example', the first & won't be there in the url. More over the server code doesn't work differently with the first &